# email validation (1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'email'")

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have two email fields in registration to validate that email is correct:

Here's my form:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email1 = forms.EmailField(label="El.paštas")
    email2 = forms.EmailField(label="Pakartokite el. paštą")

    class Meta:
        model = AuthUser
        fields = ("email1", "email2", "first_name", "last_name", "password", "city", "other_city", "age", "accepts_emails")
        widgets = {
            "password": forms.PasswordInput(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["city"].queryset = City.objects.filter(other_city=False)

        for field_name in self.fields:
            field = self.fields.get(field_name)

            if field and field_name != "accepts_emails" and field_name != "other_city":
                field.widget.attrs.update({"class": "form-control"})

    def clean_email2(self):
        email1 = self.cleaned_data["email1"]
        email2 = self.cleaned_data["email2"]

        if email1 and email2 and email1 != email2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("El. pašto adresai nesutampa.")

        try:
            AuthUser._default_manager.get(email=email1)
        except AuthUser.DoesNotExist:
            return email1

        raise forms.ValidationError("Toks el. paštas jau naudojamas.")
```

When I try to save my model I get the error saying :

```
IntegrityError at /registracija/
(1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'email'")
```

Please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: The "Duplicate entry" error is because you have a unique key in `email`. However, your fields are `email1` and `email2`. Have you migrated the app?

Comment: what do you mean migrated ?

Comment: I mean South migrations of your app, in order to update your model AuthUser in the database.

Comment: What's your `AuthUser` model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the `save()` method and set user's `email` field there:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email1']
    user.save()
    return user
```